# Reg Delete Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, regedit

I tried to delete a map/key in regedit using a batch file
I used this command but this gives me an error.

```
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Scaling] /v Scaling /f
```

I tried to remove `Scaling` without a Windows message

the error message:

```
ERROR: the system was unable to find the specified Registry key or value
ERROR invalid key name
```

Comment: My windows 7 has no Scaling key.

Comment: What Windows version do you use? Open Regedit and check if that key exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start *Regedit* and check if that key exists and has some values set:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Scaling
```

If it does, it's value can be changed by running the command in Admin Cmd Prompt:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Scaling" /v Scaling /f REG_DWORD /d 96
```

You can also delete the entire key, but not its value, though it can be set to 0. You need to try what works for a particular setting, it may vary for different apps.

Answer (score 0):

You copied a square bracket from the reg file. Remove it

DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Scaling **HERE - ]** /v Scaling /f

Comment: Thank you for your fast response i changed it to : reg DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Scaling /v Scaling /f

But that did not solve the issue